# How to convert hardcoded enum to different language?

Tags: java, enums, internationalization

I have an enum that is autogenerated of a webservice I use, thus I cannot modify this enum class as further update would override it.

I would like to provide translation for the enum:

```
//I cannot modify this class
public enum Time {
    PAST("Past"), PRESENT("Present"), FUTURE("Future");
    private final String value;
}


//my code    
Time time = getTimeFromWebservice();
String translation;

switch(time.value()) {
   case: "Past": translation = "Vergangenheit"; break;
   case: "Present": translation = "Gegenwart"; break;
   case: "Future": translation = "Zukunft"; break;
}
```

How could I improve this?

Comment: First of all, I would switch on the enum values themselves instead of their string value: `switch (time) { case PAST: ... case PRESENT: ... }`

Comment: oh yes, that's way better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot dynamically extend/modify enums at runtime. They are treated like constants.

Usually if you want to do internationlization, all translations are loaded from a `ResourceBundle`. You can use the enum literal as key:

```
String translation = bundle.getString(time.name());
```

Or maybe you want to prefix the key:

```
String translation = bundle.getString("myprefix." + time.name());

// or use full qualified name:
String translation = bundle.getString(time.getClass().getCanonicalName() + "." + time.name());
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html for details.