# Android - localization of an enum

Tags: android, enums, localization, internationalization, translation

I have to make a todo app translated to multiple languages.

I have an enum containing 3 levels (low, medium, high) and I also use it to reference priority labels. This is how it looks:

```
public enum Priority {
    LOW(R.drawable.priority_low),
    MEDIUM(R.drawable.priority_medium),
    HIGH(R.drawable.priority_high);

    private int drawableResource;

    Priority(int drawableResource) {
        this.drawableResource = drawableResource;
    }

    public int getDrawableResource() {
        return drawableResource;
    }
}
```

And this is how I create some sample todo items:

```
private TodoItemDao() {
    todoItems.add(new TodoItem("pet shop", new Date(), "buy a nice zombie pig", Priority.HIGH));
    todoItems.add(new TodoItem("barber", new Date(), "cut lion's hair", Priority.MEDIUM));
    todoItems.add(new TodoItem("mine", new Date(), "we need redstones", Priority.LOW));
}
```

So in this scene, how do I translate todo priority levels to different languages? I usually do it like

```
    titleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_title);
```

...but have no idea how to do it within an enum and how to set priority level at item creation. Any idea?

**EDIT:**

I'm affraid I wasn't clear enough. With this line:

```
titleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_title);
```

I wanted to show that I already use strings.xml. I just had no idea how to use it with an enum.

Comment: This may be of use to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20287009/how-to-convert-hardcoded-enum-to-different-language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, use strings.xml and add the translations. Do it for however many languages you have.

A suggestion is you add the following to your enum or somewhere else you can access it:

```
public String getPriorityName(Priority ref, Context c){
    switch(ref){
        case Priority.LOW:
            return c.getString(R.string.priorityLowDescription);
            break;

        (Showing only one here, but you can see the pattern)
    }
}
```

This takes in your priority instance, and based on that returns an appropriate String from `strings.xml`. This means it will get the String in the language your device is set to(or the user set it manually to, depending on settings)

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it directly from an enum.  Put the translations in your strings.xml file as normal.  Write a function `int mapToStringResource(Priority)` that converts from a Priority to the correct id.  Call `setText(mapToStringResource(priority))` to set the text.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding a function through extension to my enum `Document.DocType` (as the enum code is generated - otherwise I would have added it directly) like so:

```
fun Document.DocType.mapToStringResource() : Int {
when (this) {
    Document.DocType.PDF -> return R.string.documents_docType_PDF
    else -> {
        return 0
    }
}
```

(Note: returning 0 will crash if the resource does not exist. Maybe it's better to make it optional or have a default string resources for "not-found")

And then use it in Jetpack Compose like this:

```
Text(text = stringResource(document.docType.mapToStringResource()))
```